# RealityKit – Wall Surface Area Detection

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

With RealityKit and SwiftUI I’m trying to place an entity object in the corners of a wall and then measure the distances between them to measure the surface area of a wall and tent the selected wall blue as if it’s selected text, I wish I had code to show for my attempts but I don’t know where to even start with a project like this, does someone have any resources I should look into with RealityKit that can point me in the right direction, or sample code I could modify to my needs?

I truthfully haven’t started with the RealityKit aspect of my app yet, I have all other aspects near completion though and ready to be polished.

Comment: You can click on [edit] link below your post to make corrections and add more information

Comment: Is there anyone that can help?